# Probability $Y>X$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The lifetime $X$ of Machine 1 and the lifetime $Y$ of Machine 2 are independent and have density functions

$f_1(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{x}{2} & 0<x<2\\0 & otherwise \\ \end{cases}$

$f_2(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{2}{y^2} & 1<y<2 \\ 0 & otherwise\\ \end{cases}$

What is the probability that Machine 2 outlives Machine 1?

I tried setting the bounds to the bounds given in the piecewise function (i.e. $0<x<2, 1<y<2$) and I multiplied the two piecewise functions together, then took the integral and I got $1$. I don't believe that is correct, but these bounds were all I could think of. Maybe I messed up. Thank you for helping in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in order to calculate

$$\mathbb{P}[Y>X]$$

you have to evaluate the purple area below

[image]

calculated as a double integral of $f_X(x)f_Y(y)$, due to independence

That is

$$\mathbb{P}[Y>X]=\int_1^2\frac{2}{y^2}\left[\int_0^y \frac{x}{2}dx  \right]dy=\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
P(Y>X)=\iint_{D}f(x,y)\;dxdy
$$
where $f(x,y)=f_1(x)f_2(y)$ and
$$
D=\color{red}{\{y>x\}}\cap [0,2]\times[1,2].
$$

If you missed the part $\{y>x\}$, the integral would be $1$.